# cmake vs gmake for qtcreator project

Tags: c, qt, cmake, gnu-make

I am attempting to use QtCreator as an IDE for a straight C project. The reason is that I am comfortable with QtCreator and I want a visual IDE for stepping through this new project I am working on. My development box and my deployment box are different, but both of those have gmake on them. QtCreator requires cmake, which I dont mind putting on my development box, but my deployment box is not going to have cmake.

Am I OK to build my software on the Qt box, and be sure it will deploy on the deployment box?

Edit: to be clear, the existing code base already has a makefile structure going, and I'd rather not interrupt that. If I can set my project up to use those existing targets and such it would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your project is using CMake as build system, then you should have it installed on the machine you are building. You can't pregenerate Makefile's and then just run `make` on the other box.

Well, you actually can, but then you will probably need same compiler versions, libs/headers located in same paths and etc. So generally it's not good idea.

As for deploying already compiled binaries - it have no relation to CMake. The general rule there is that you should have same shared libraries on both machines. Linking your project statically allows deploying single fat executable/library, without any additional dependencies.